# using eval to programmatically define an SQLQuery q object

Tags: eval, python, sqlobject

I'm using SQLObject and want to programmatically build a query using the .q objects (or some other way) -- but do not want to revert to actual SQL.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
column = 'name'
value = 'todd'
Users.select(Users.q.column==value)
```

I've got this:

```
Users.select(eval('Users.q.%s' % column)==value)
```

But it just feels "wrong" -- is this the "correct" (or more aptly, "pythonic") way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Users.select(getattr(Users.q, column)==value)
```

Comment: d'oh!  i'm using setattr to achieve the same thing on the input end, i should have thought about getattr on the output end.  thank you!